# Javascript Promise and Then with Http Services not running in order

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to use a Promise followed up with a then() to get some code to run asynchronously. My goal is when the addTimeToTimecard() function runs, the promise will run another function with a http request inside of it, and then return to the then() and run the second http service.

```
addTimeToTimecard() {

const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.checkAndCreateTimecard();
  resolve();
});

// everything in the function above needs to complete before the upcoming http request
promise.then(() => {
console.log("do the patch")

 this.httpService.patch('setTimeIn/', { timeVar: "TimeIn", timeAmount: this.time1 }).subscribe()

})

  checkAndCreateTimecard() {
    this.httpService.get('timecard/fullTimecard/' + this.workDate).subscribe((ft: any) => {
      console.log("got the timecard")
  )}
 }

//output:
do the patch
ERROR timecard doesn't exist
got the timecard
```

I've been having to resort to using SetTimeout() to get code like this to work, but I know using Promises or async/await is a better way to do things. What am I doing wrong here and what is a best practice for using promises?

Comment: It is not clear to me why you thought that *would* work. The call to `resolve` is unrelated to the asynchronous operation inside `checkAndCreateTimecard`.

Comment: You're mixing Promises and Observables pretty freely there. Pick one and use it consistently and you'll have a better time of it. Also, if you find yourself using `new Promise` for any reason other than to deal with another framework that only uses callbacks, you're probably headed down the wrong track.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was following a guide to Promise that used that function, but clearly I wasn't using it right.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I suppose I should stick to the Observables, but I was unable to get multiple services to work without chaining them directly together inside the subscribe function. I have several other functions calling the checkAndCreateTimecard() function so I didn't want to duplicate that code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as you are using Angular it may make much more sense to combine the requests using `switchMap` operator:

```js
addTimeToTimecard() {
  return this.checkAndCreateTimecard()
    .pipe(switchMap(data => {
      return this.httpService.patch("setTimeIn/", { timeVar: "TimeIn", timeAmount: this.time1 });
    });
}

checkAndCreateTimecard() {
  return this.httpService.get("timecard/fullTimecard/" + this.workDate);
}
```

If you really want to use promises for some reason [toPromise operator] (https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/topromise) could help you.

```
addTimeToTimecard() {
  return this.checkAndCreateTimecard()
    .then(data => {
      return this.httpService.patch("setTimeIn/", { timeVar: "TimeIn", timeAmount: this.time1 }).toPromise();
    })
}

checkAndCreateTimecard() {
  return this.httpService.get("timecard/fullTimecard/" + this.workDate).toPromise();
}
```

P.S. I would recommend to live with Observables

Comment: I tried this out, but the "then()" never triggered. I also need the subscribe() to get the data from the http request. It seems the best way to do this would be to have a function inside of subscribe() run what the switchMap() function is doing.

Comment: @Danchat I wrote an example for you here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i3qm7z
When you call `toPromise` on observable it makes a subscription, so you don't need to care about it. So Promise version of `addTimeToTimecard` sends a request just after being called, but Observables version, return an observable and sends a request when you subscribe to this observable.

Comment: The stackblitz code didn't work for me, but this paints a clearer picture of how to use observables and promises. Thanks for putting that together!